# Places Room List API returns cached data

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have removed 4 existing room lists using `Remove-DistributionGroup` cmdlet. 
I have added 1 new room list using `New-DistributionGroup` cmdlet.
However when calling the API

> https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/places/microsoft.graph.roomlist

(using cURL)
with Application Permissions to `Places.ReadAll`, the API returns the old roomlists and not the new one.
However when calling EWS via EWS Java SDK, the output is as expected i.e. it only shows the new roomlist. 
The Office365 Web app also shows the old room lists in the `Browse for more rooms` option.
Is the `places` resource returning cached data? If so what is the refresh interval here?

**Update** (Feb'20) Issue is no longer happening. Changes to roomlists are reflected instantaneously

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can take up to 60 hrs to show up in the Places API and web app. We are working on making this instant and should have this ready by end of Jan 2020.

Comment: Victoria, It sounds like you're on top of the issue. We're currently working on a production app that relies on the Places API. Needs to be ready before Basic Authentication is turned off on Office 365 later this year! Is there anywhere we can follow up on the status of the issue? Many thx.

Comment: Currently experiencing a delay as well after removing a room from a room list and still seeing it in Graph API calls; will check again on Monday to see if it has dropped off the list by then.

Comment: @TylerH over the years I have noticed that there is a dependency on the geo-location of Azure. Room mailboxes are created in specific geo-location, typically the default region of the Azure tenant. When calling Graph API from a program, depending on source geo-location of the calling program, Graph API resolves to a Azure data-center nearest to it, which may or may not be the same as the source mailboxes' geo-location. The above delay in replication will increase if such a difference in geo-location happens. This is purely speculative and observed by trial-and-error

Comment: Can confirm after 72 hours (checked on a Monday morning), a room I had removed from a room list on the previous Friday was finally gone in the API call results after still showing up the day it was removed.