# Places room endpoint not returning all rooms

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

If I call the endpoint /places/microsoft.graph.room I only get some of the rooms. If I use the findRooms method I can see all the rooms. The rooms (mailboxes) all have identical permissions. The rooms that are not visible were created in the last couple of hours.

Is there still some 60 hour cache here like mentioned in another question (which is about room lists and not rooms): [Places Room List API returns cached data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58877297/places-room-list-api-returns-cached-data)?

Comment: Exactly the same issue here. In addition, changes to Capacity, Address or other properties of visible meeting rooms do not show up in /places. Moreover, the same rooms and changes missing from /places are also missing in OWA. Rooms were added and changed 24 hours ago. I will check again after 60 hours have passed.

Comment: @flip Any recollection if 60 hours was all you needed to wait?

Comment: After having this issue, I found that after 60 hours (I didn't check until 72 hours had passed) it was automatically resolved for me as well. Voting to close as a dupe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Places Room List API returns cached data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58877297/places-room-list-api-returns-cached-data)